# GDB not found when MINGW-HOME in Eclipse is a relative path

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, mingw, eclipse-cdt

When I replace the absolute path of `MINGW-HOME` with a Relative Path, the C code compiles and runs with a warning `Toolchain "MinGW GCC" is not detected`. And when i try to debug, i get the following error message. `Cannot run program "gdb"`. 
I only get this problem when the path to the `MINGW-HOME` is  written as a relative. I am also very sure that the relative path is correct because, the program can compile and run without an error, but just doesn't debug.

Here is the setting with the absolute paths:

[image]

Here is the setting with the relative paths and the warning:

[image]

Here is the error message gotten while trying to debug

[image]

Comment: Relative to what? In case to the workspace, try type _Directory_ instead of _String_ that starts with `${workspace_loc}/..`, or in case to the project _CUR_ `${workspace_loc:/CUR}/../..`.

Comment: Thank you very much Howlger. I used  "${workspace_loc:/CUR}/../.." and It works perfect. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use as **type *Directory*** instead of *String* and start the *Value* with:

- for relative to the workspace: `${workspace_loc}/../../..`...
- for relative to the project `CUR`: `${workspace_loc:/CUR}/../..`...

Comment: Thank you very much Howlger. I used "${workspace_loc:/CUR}/../.." and It works perfect. :)